# VS2017(C#) コンソールアプリでraspberry piへssh接続に関しての質問です．

Tags: c#, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, ssh

VS2017(C#)とRaspberry pi3 ModelBを使って，プログラム内でssh接続をしようとしています．

VS2017のコンソールアプリの中で，SshNetライブラリを参照し,同じルータに無線でつながったraspberry piへssh接続をしたいという感じです．

プログラムはこのようになっております．

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Renci.SshNet;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // 接続先のホスト名またはIPアドレス
                var hostNameOrIpAddr = "xxx.xxx.x.x";

                // 接続先のポート番号
                var portNo = 22;

                // ログインユーザー名
                var userName = "pi";

                // ログインパスワード
                var passWord = "xxxxxxxx";

                // コネクション情報
                ConnectionInfo info = new ConnectionInfo(hostNameOrIpAddr, portNo, userName,
                    new AuthenticationMethod[] {
                        new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(userName, passWord)
                        /* PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod("キーの場所")を指定することでssh-key認証にも対応しています */
                    }
                );

                // クライアント作成
                SshClient ssh = new SshClient(info);

                // 接続開始
                ssh.Connect();

                if (ssh.IsConnected)
                {
                    // 接続に成功した（接続状態である）
                    Console.WriteLine("[OK] SSH Connection succeeded!!");
                }
                else
                {
                    // 接続に失敗した（未接続状態である）
                    Console.WriteLine("[NG] SSH Connection failed!!");
                    return;
                }

                // 接続終了
                ssh.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // エラー発生時
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

そして，現状 System.Exception{System.Net.Sockets.SocketException}
          対象のコンピュータによって拒否されたため，接続できませんでした

というエラーメッセージが表示されています．

raspberry piとVSを扱っている別のpcはそれぞれ同じルータに無線で接続されています．
また，teratermなどのターミナルからはssh接続が可能です．なお，pcはwindows7です．

いろいろと自分なりに調べて改善しようといたしましたが，初心者で知識不足ということもあり
改善することができませんでした．

どなたか詳しい方，お知恵をお貸ししていただきたいです．

よろしくお願いいたします．